# Why all my downloads are saved as CRDOWNLOAD in shared folder when try to download via selenium edge-webdriver?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge

I am attempting to download a file in a shared folder using Selenium WebDriver in Python. I am using the following code:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver

pathtodownload = "\\\\shared folder"
driverpath = "edge driver path"

options = Options()
prefs = {"download.default_directory": pathtodownload}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs);

service = Service(driverpath)
driver = webdriver.Edge(service=service, options=options)
```

However, the file is only downloading partially as CRDOWNLOAD files. When attempting to download manually, the file is downloading completely to the default download folder or even after I change it to the shared folder. What could be causing this issue?

Comment: you're probably quitting the driver before the download is complete.  (the .crdownload file is a partial download)